# The Server on Shared Hosting Returns 500 Server Error on POST Request while it is working fine on my machine

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, asynchronous, server

I've just implemented an AJAX request calling POST method and add it in loop to have multiple responses. It's working fine on my machine on localhost but when I hosted it on Bluehost Shared Hosting, some requests have OK response (200) and others have (500) Server error using PHP 7.2.

This is my view.blade.php

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
   $.ajax({
     url:'/download',
     method: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     success:function(data){
        if(data['status'] == '0') {alert('SUCCESS FOR ' + i);}
        else {alert('ERROR FOR ' + i);}
     }
   });
}
```

This is my MainController.php

```
function download(Request $request){
   //DO STUFF
   return response()->json(['status'=>'0']); //return '1' if success and '0' if failure
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated ?

Comment: Check your server logs.  How should we know what's inside them?

Comment: Check your error log, maybe it has something to do with file permissions

Comment: Nothing in my error log, I've checked it multiple times

Comment: A 500 error should *always* go to an error log of some sort. Might be in `storage/logs/laravel.log`, might be in your webserver's logs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an issue with the async nature of the ajax calls.  Localhost is likely transmitting fast and so the data is moving one at a time.  On your shared host, it may be taking longer and thus screwing up something.  That something could very well be the variable scope.  I see you are calling for `i` within the response.  That `i` may not be the one your method expects.  Hard to tell without more info, but if this is the issue...:

A potentially better way to solve the scope problem is to give each ajax function its own copy of variable `i` so we always know which `i` used to be and should be for each AJAX call.

Something like this might help:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i ++)
{
  $.ajax(
  {
     method: 'POST',
     url:'/download',
     loopI: i, // Capture the current value of 'i'.
     success: function(data)
     {
        i = this.loopI; // your specific scoped i
      // ETC
```

You can also test with a simple : `async: false,` in your ajax, but I might use the more clear solution above as a permanent fix.